# using Full join in sql server

Tags: sql-server, inner-join, outer-join

i have 2 table data want join all together,each table are less 1 row date 
example : table A have 8 row date and table b also have 8 row date but both table have 1 row date is different .i want my result show out as 10 row

table A

```
RN  USERID  ClockIn CHECKTIME   badgenumber
1   6       8:24AM  2017-03-02  107
1   6       7:57AM  2017-03-03  107
1   6       8:23AM  2017-03-06  107
1   6       8:26AM  2017-03-07  107
1   6       8:57AM  2017-03-08  107
1   6       8:33AM  2017-03-09  107
1   6       8:36AM  2017-03-10  107
1   6      8:15AM   2017-03-13  107
```

table B

```
RN  USERID  ClockOut    CHECKTIME   badgenumber
1   6       9:31PM      2017-03-01  107
1   6       10:28PM     2017-03-02  107
1   6       8:22PM      2017-03-03  107
1   6       9:18PM      2017-03-06  107
1   6       9:48PM      2017-03-07  107
1   6       9:11PM      2017-03-08  107
1   6       11:31PM     2017-03-09  107
1   6       6:30PM      2017-03-10  107
```

my result show as

```
SELECT #clockin.ClockIn, #clockOut.ClockOut,#clockin.USERID,#clockin.CHECKTIME
FROM #clockin
FULL JOIN #clockOut
ON #clockin.CHECKTIME=#clockOut.CHECKTIME
where #clockin.userid = 6 and #clockOut.userid = 6
ORDER BY #clockin.userid;
```

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
    
        <h2>result</h2>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcdSS.png" alt="result" >
    
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of your `where` clause, you are filtering out rows where `x.userid` is `null` (where there is no match). This essentially turns your `full join` into an `inner join`. You can use `coalesce()` to return the first non-null value from your two columns and compare that to `6` like so:

```
SELECT #clockin.ClockIn, #clockOut.ClockOut,#clockin.USERID,#clockin.CHECKTIME
FROM #clockin
  FULL JOIN #clockOut
    ON #clockin.CHECKTIME=#clockOut.CHECKTIME
where coalesce(#clockin.userid,#clockOut.userid)=6
ORDER BY #clockin.userid;
```

Comment: @ShanweiLim Updated

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ClockIn, ClockOut,
       ISNULL(ci.USERID, co.USERID) AS USERID,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ISNULL(ci.CHECKTIME, co.CHECKTIME), 101) AS CHECKTIME
FROM #ClockIn AS ci
FULL JOIN #ClockOut AS co ON (co.CHECKTIME = ci.CHECKTIME);
```

This should give your desired output for the sample data. However you may have to consider adding RN, USERID etc. in the JOIN filter depending on what you want.

The ISNULL() replaces the NULL id of ClockIn with the id from ClockOut.

Comment: Please let me know the example badgenumber and userid of other rows if any exist.